# Pygame displays a black screen when i draw a rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried to implement the snake game tutorial from the [link](https://theailearner.com/2018/10/06/creating-a-snake-game-with-pygame/) but the screen closes instantly after running the .py file. I have looked up for the screen instantly closing error and tried fixing it by adding a run block but now the screen just becomes black whenever I try to draw a rectangle.

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_AUDIODRIVER'] = 'dsp'
import pygame
import sys
import random
import subprocess

import pygame
pygame.init()


display_width = 500 
display_height = 500    
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
window_color= (200,200,200)
red = (255,0,0)  
black = (0,0,0)
apple_image = pygame.image.load('apple.jpg') 
snake_head = [250,250] 
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake AI")
snake_position = [[250,250],[240,250],[230,250]] 
apple_position = [random.randrange(1,50)*10,random.randrange(1,50)*10]

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run =False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            command = "python sample.py"
            subprocess.call(command)

    
    def display_snake(snake_position):
        for position in snake_position:
            pygame.draw.rect(display,red,pygame.Rect(position[0],position[1],10,10))
    

    def display_apple(display,apple_position, apple):
        display.blit(apple,(apple_position[0], apple_position[1]))
    
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please don't request help "asap".  Even "please help me" is not necessary.  That is what everyone is here for.

Comment: Where are your `display_apple()` and `display_snake()` functions called??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your definitions of `display_apple()` and `display_snake()` where the calls to them should be.

Take the definitions of the `display_apple()` and `display_snake()` functions out of the while loop and move them up top somewhere. Where they used to be defined, call them instead. You will see your snake and apple show up on the screen.

```py
def display_snake(snake_position):
    for position in snake_position:
        pygame.draw.rect(display,red,pygame.Rect(position[0],position[1],10,10))
    

def display_apple(display,apple_position, apple):
    display.blit(apple,(apple_position[0], apple_position[1]))

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run =False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            command = "python sample.py"
            subprocess.call(command)

    display_apple(display, apple_position, apple_image)
    display_snake(snake_position)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have put the definitions just above the `while` loop so you can see them, but I would normally define them higher up, before the `pygame.init()` call would be a good place.

You generally want your function definitions and class definitions (if you have any, but you do not at the moment) to be separated from the executed code.

In fact I prefer to put the main body of the executing code inside a function as well, usually that function gets called `main()`, and then just call that function. That means there is no real executing code at the top level, other than the call of the function `main()`. Doing that does require you to be careful about global variables though and would cause you some problems here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your pygame.quit() command under the check events 'for' loop. Because what its currently doing is running through your program and once it completes the main loop once it quits:

```
while True: # you don't need a flag here, unless 
            # you have an activation button of

   for event in pygame.event.get():

      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          command = "python sample.py"
          subprocess.call(command)
```

Also in general a could practice would be to refactor all your above code into fuctions or complete them in different modules and import them as objects into a so called `main.py` file (which is this one, contains main game loop).

Comment: I have implemented the change according to the code you have suggested but it still displays the same blank black screen.

Comment: The location of `pygame.quit()` has nothing to do with OPs problem with objects not being drawn. The `quit()` is fine where it is, though I would probably add a `break` after setting `run = False` to skip processing any remaining events, but is not that big a deal generally.